# Config for Minimum distance between 2 elements(shapes) with ports in JointJS + ElkJS?

Tags: jointjs, eclipse-elk

Attached image, it is seen that the link is too small, I need the elements to be farther apart so that the link label and port labels is seen

Is there a way to specify the minimum distance between the elements(shapes) with ports in JointJS + elkJS?also the link between them should be of a specific length.
Issue faced: There are 2 squares and the link between them is too tiny, unable to put labels for link & ports.

Tried port label placement, port order etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you meant to attach an image, but no image is visible.

There are many layout options for nodes and edges available here:
https://www.eclipse.org/elk/reference/options.html

You could increase the distance between nodes via the `Node Node Between Layers Spacing` option.
https://www.eclipse.org/elk/reference/options/org-eclipse-elk-layered-spacing-nodeNodeBetweenLayers.html

You could use it as follows:

```js
"layoutOptions": {
    "spacing.nodeNodeBetweenLayers": 50
},
```

There are also many options for placing labels, etc.